# How to output items in JSX from an array of items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a small similar array of

`const arr = [{ "0": "First Item", "1": "Second Item", "2": "Third Item"}]`

And I want to output that in JSX.

This is what I have https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-bose-wgmbny?file=/src/App.js. As you can see, it only outputs the first element of the array.

I have tried using forEach and for loops to no avail. (And developers tell me you should use .map for JSX)

I also tried this:

```
arr.map((item, index) => (
    <p>{item[index]}</p>
))
```

I just want the map to output:

"First Item"
"Second Item"
"Third Item"

but it just stops at "First Item"

Comment: You have an array with a single object in that tries to behave like an array. Is that intentional or did you try to do `[ "First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item" ]`?

Comment: even with your data structure which i find strange you could still achieve it. `Object.values(arr[0]).map((item, index) => (
    <p>{item}</p>
))`

Comment: const testArry = [
    {
      "0": "First Item"
    },
    {
      "1": "Second Item"
    },
    {
      "2": "Third Item"
    }
  ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@steve You have to consider multiple points here

1. Your array contains an object, so the length of array is 1 and will only iterate once.
2. Inside your array, you have an object, and accessing item[index] fetches the first index of the object, hence the result.
   To fix this

**Approach 1**

```html
return (
    <div className="App">
      {testArry.map((item, index) => {
        const obj = Object.values(item).map(item1 => item1)
        return obj;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

**Approach 2**

```js
const testArry = ["First Iteam", "Second Item", "Third Item"];

return (
    <div className="App">
      {testArry.map((item, index) => {
        return item
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Approach 1 was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [{ "0": "First Item", "1": "Second Item", "2": "Third Item"}]
```

It's an array with a single object as its element.
When you use map function on `arr` like this:

```
arr.map((item, index) => item[index])
```

It iterates over the elements in `arr`, and for each element (which is the single object in this case) it returns property with key `index` (which is index of current `map` iteration). So actually you are invoking `arr[0][0]` here.

Correct array would be:

```
const arr = ["First Item", "Second Item", "Third Item"];
```

Then you can print each item:

```js
  return (
    <div className="App">{arr.map((item) => item)}</div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it is the wrong array, but I am getting data from a JSON, so it's automatically an object.

Answer (score 0):

in your example array only have 1 object

and you loop through it

and map will loop only once. it will return your object;

your item is **{ "0": "First Item", "1": "Second Item", "2": "Third Item"}**;

and **index always 0** because it will loop only once.

and you use **item[index]**

which means your item is object above

and **item[index]** means only **key of object**

```js
const arr = [{ "0": "First Item", "1": "Second Item", "2": "Third Item"}];

// here is in your array only have 1 element

//{ "0": "First Item", "1": "Second Item", "2": "Third Item"}

// and if you console it you will see that item is
// { "0": "First Item", "1": "Second Item", "2": "Third Item"}


console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[0][0]);
arr.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item[index]);
    console.log(item);
});

// so you should do
const arr1 = [{ "0": "First Item"}, {"1": "Second Item"}, {"2": "Third Item"}];

arr1.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(item[index]);
  console.log(item);
});
```